# How to change checked (selected) radio button by state value

Tags: reactjs

My react state set by an **API** object. I have 2 radio buttons and I want to change the **checked** radio button according to the state value.

I have onChange function to handle set state if user change the radio button later.

```
this.state = {
    refundableStatus: 'Refundable',
}


handleRefundableStatus = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        refundableStatus: e.target.value
    })
}


<input
    type="radio"
    label="Refundable"
    name="refundable-status"
    id="refundableCheck"
    value="Refundable"
    onChange={(e) => this.handleServiceFeeTypeFrom(e)}
/>

    <input
        type="radio"
        label="Non-Refundable"
        name="refundable-status"
        id="nonRefundableCheck"
        value="Non-Refundable"
        onChange={(e) => this.handleServiceFeeTypeFrom(e)}
/>
```

I want to change the checked radio button as "Refundable". How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `checked` attribute to `input` based on `state`,

```
<input
    type="radio"
    label="Refundable"
    name="refundable-status"
    id="refundableCheck"
    value="Refundable"
    checked={this.state.refundableStatus === "Refundable"}
    onChange={(e) => this.handleServiceFeeTypeFrom(e)}
/>

<input
   type="radio"
   label="Non-Refundable"
   name="refundable-status"
   id="nonRefundableCheck"
   value="Non-Refundable"
   checked={this.state.refundableStatus !== "Refundable"}
   onChange={(e) => this.handleServiceFeeTypeFrom(e)}
/>
```